# More traditional word for 'now-centric'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for an adjective that means *privileging the now* or *to believe the present is more important or better than any other time*. Analogous to *anthropocentric*.

I believe *now-centric* is clear enough but I'd rather not ignore a more commonly used and recognized word.

**Can you use it in a sentence?**

"In her study of history she remained very *now-centric*; nothing mattered except for how it related to the present."

Comment: Presentist, maybe?

Comment: @bof I think that fits pretty well. I'd vote you if you made it a solid answer

Comment: [_Present-minded_](https://www.google.ca/search?safe=off&ei=5NU1WpaSJcisjwTD6oqQBg&q=%22present-minded%22&oq=%22present-minded%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1l8j0i8i30k1.396067.399117.0.399336.16.16.0.0.0.0.134.1418.12j4.16.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.16.1412...0j35i39k1j0i67k1j0i131k1j0i20i263k1.0.li4JsRnDH8I) is somewhat common and it is in _OED_ also. _Present-centric_ comes to mind also but it is very uncommon.

Comment: I would have preferred if you'd written 'Present-minded is in the center of the OED; present-centric comes to mind also' @ermanen

Comment: @ermanen Haha just enjoyed the 'present-**centric** comes to **mind** and was trying to make it even more chiastic

Answer (score 2):

The *Journal of Youth Studies* uses the word 'present-focused' but I cannot find it in any online dictionary.

> Future-oriented or **present-focused**? The role of social support and identity styles

[Journal of Youth Studies](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13676261.2015.1059925?journalCode=cjys20)

Answer (score 0):

The closest that I can find is *present-centric*. I did a Google search, and there are a few hits (including in a couple of books). There are also hits for *now-centric*. But you gave *anthropocentric* as an example, and the books that contain *present-centric* include those related to the humanities.